# NSLog style debug messages from C code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios

I have some C code in a static library that I'm compiling into an iPhone app. I'd like to print some debug messages to the console; is there something like NSLog I should use? I'm guessing NSLog only works for the Objective-C parts of the program.

EDIT: fprintf(stdout, fmt...) and fprintf(stderr, fmt...) don't work either.. any idea why they don't? Should they work?

Comment: Plain old `printf` seems to work for some code I'm working on.

Comment: So I figured out that the output shows up in the console in Xcode, but not the console in organizer.. I guess that was what I was missing

Comment: I've never quite figured out what shows up in Organizer.  Seems to randomly select lines.

Comment: I'm sure that fprintf output used to show up in the organizer console.. maybe its something to do with Xcode 4.3

Comment: I'm amazed when anything works with Xcode 4.

Comment: printf works for me in iOS 5 but not in iOS 6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can always do the classic:

```
fprintf(stderr, "hi, this is a log line: %s", aStringVariable);
```

Comment: try `fprintf(stdout,...);` then... either stderr or stdout are the magic stream identifiers that will cause the output appear in your console.

Comment: yup, tried both of those, and neither worked. I can set breakpoints in the same code, and the Xcode debugger breaks at those points.. so the code is definitely running on the device.

Comment: Just for giggles, try running your app from the Terminal and see if any lines appear there.  Or in Console.app.

Comment: That wouldn't really help, because I'm debugging some NEON code which won't run on x86..

Comment: yep... I was going to suggest looking in the console in XCode next.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 10):

You can make a wrapper for NSLog if you mix Objective-C code like this:

### log.h

```
void debug(const char *message, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
```

### log.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "log.h"

void debug(const char *message,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, message);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:message] arguments:args]);
    va_end(args);
}
```

and then, in your C file:

```
#include "log.h"
...
debug("hello world! variable: %d", num);
```

Answer (score 4):

Other solution:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
extern "C" void NSLog(CFStringRef format, ...);

#define MyLog(fmt, ...) \
{ \
    NSLog(CFSTR(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__); \
}

MyLog("val = %d, str = %s", 123, "abc");
```

Comment: removing ``extern "C"`` worked for me, to let it compile and fix "error: expected identifier or '(' "

Answer (score 3):

While printf will show up if you're debugging from XCode, it won't show up in the Organizer Console.  You can use what NSLog uses: [CFLog or syslog](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CFLog).

Comment: Isn't CFLog a private API for Apple's use only ?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <asl.h>
...
asl_log(NULL, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_ERR, "Hi There!");
```

Note that lower priority levels such as `ASL_LEVEL_INFO` may not show up in console.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see printf or fprintf statements. Try running some of the code in the library but from the terminal, something should appear if not. A much more complicated (and even silly/stupid/wrong) method that I will guarantee you that will work would be:

```
sprintf(message,"This is a log line %s",someString);
system("echo %s",message);
```

If that doesn't work then you probably have something weird in your code.

Note: This will probably only work in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the Apple System Log facility to get the output into the device console.

Check the functions in usr/asl.h.

```
asl_open
asl_new
asl_set
asl_log
asl_free
```

Answer (score 0):

While printf will show up if you're debugging from XCode, it won't show up in the Organizer Console. You can run the following command to print only to device's console:

```
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "log string");
```

You will also need to #include <sys/syslog.h> for syslog and LOG_WARNING to be explicitly declared